# jquery checked checkbox IE problem

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue verifying if a checkbox is checked using jquery on Internet Explorer.
This is the code I'm using:

```
if ($('#chkjq_1').attr('checked') == true)
```

It works fine on Firefox or Chrome, but on Internet Explorer 7, the condition is always false because the browser sets the property this way:

```
<input id="chkjq_1" type="checkbox" CHECKED/> IE7
```

And the right way is the following: (Firefox, Chrome):

```
<input id="chkjq_1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/> FF, Chrome, etc
```

What should I do to avoid this issue on Internet Explorer 7; is there a generic way in jquery to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Comment: What is responsible for generating your input tags?  Is this an ASP.NET server control or something similar?  Best to focus on why the tag is being rendered incorrectly and see if you can address that; then the jQuery should just work.

Comment: lidermin, you mean jquery UI 1.7.2, which needs jquery 1.3+ to run; Anyway, the answers you have are working with any jquery 1.0+

Comment: Sorry, You are right, I meant jquery 1.3.2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('#chkjq_1').is(':checked'))
{
  // more code
}
```

Comment: it works for me also . in case of my 'CHECKED' is not working in IE9 and i change it to 'checked' and works .

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I could get to work consistently was to test like this:

```
if ($('#chkjq_1').is('[CHECKED]'))
```

Using all caps on the selector like IE renders it when you open Developer Tools. Works across browsers so far as I can tell. .is(':checked') wouldn't match for me (using JQuery 1.7.1). Tested using IE 7 and IE 8 in multiple modes. Other browsers (Firefox, Safari tested) seem not to care.

Comment: This tests if the checked attribute is present. But in firefox, if I unckeck a checkbox, is('CHECKED') is still true.

Comment: That's because you need is(':CHECKED')

Answer (score 1):

"change" event of checkbox in IE is triggered weirdly.

This can be solved as:-
1.) bind the onclick event of input checkbox to required target function to be fired
2.) in the target function, check the status of the checkbox by checking the "checked" attribute via-

```
if ($('#chkBox').attr("checked") == "checked"){
      // do something ----or .attr("checked", "checked"); ---for another checkbox
}else{
      // do something else ----or .removeAttr("checked"); ---for another checkbox
}
```