# jQuery if checkbox is not checked issue

Tags: jquery, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

I am having an issue picking up when a checkbox is not checked.

Here is my sample code:

```
$(".get-the-look ul input").click(function(){
    if("this:checked") {
        var product = $(this).attr('alt');
        $("#bob div").remove('.'+product);
    } else {
        alert('asdasd');
    }
});
```

But the alert (if the checkbox isn't checked) never fires... The 'else' never kicks in no matter what state the checkbox is in?

I don't see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can't pass `this:checked` as a string - it won't work as it will be interpreted as a string and always evaluate to `true`

use `$(this).is(':checked')` instead

Comment: yes $(this).is(:checked) should be used!

Comment: another bit similar q/a : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525331/jquery-checked-checkbox-ie-problem

Answer (score 2):

The string `"this:checked"` will always evaluate to `TRUE`. Try `this.checked` instead, i.e., evaluate the property `checked` on `this`:

```
if(this.checked) { ...
```

Comment: Hmm, a little late on that one :) Also, make sure that you only try to access `.checked` on `<input type="checkbox />`.

Comment: yeah :) but using native this.checked will do its job (and even faster) - gave jquery answer for consistence with the rest of the example and to show how it should be used properly.

Comment: @Tom Hu Yup! Also, I forgot the reference to [*Utilizing the awesome power of jQuery to access properties of an element*](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element) which I link to whenever I can :)